# Is there always a leaf(s) attatched to an auxillary bud?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

I'm trying to create a 3D functional-structural plant model and I need to establish some axioms.

Is it guaranteed or extremely likely that where auxiliary bud forms there's a leaf(s) attached? That's what it appears to be from most of the images I saw. If so, what usually comes first, the leaf or the bud?

More generally, is there a rule about where a leaf is guaranteed to naturally grow? Perhaps suggest some literature on this. Thank you!